# Как расшифровать трафик в Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

Как правильно настроить Wireshark что бы расшифровать TCP трафик с

> Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)

`RSA Session-ID` и `Master-Key` сохранил в файл `SomeName.keys`